# WordPress post meta array

Tags: arrays, wordpress, meta

I'm adding post meta for custom post type. The meta value is an array

```
Array (
    'value',
    'value',
    'value'
)
```

Using add_post_meta() works fine, but when I retrieve post meta, it returns a multi-dimentional array

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => value,
        [1] => value,
        [2] => value
    )
)
```

Why is a multidimentional array returned when I'm using the following

```
$myarray = get_post_meta( $postid, 'meta_key', false );
```

Comment: `get_post_meta( $postid, 'meta_key', true );` will display the data of what you recorded in `add_post_meta()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax for get_post_meta as state below reference link is

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

```
get_post_meta ( int $post_id, string $key = '', bool $single = false )
```

Retrieve post meta field for a post.

Return: (mixed) Will be an array if `$single is false`. Will be value of meta data field if `$single is true.`

Try something like below

```
get_post_meta( $postid, 'meta_key', true );
```